# how to decode json data Go

Tags: json, go

How can I get this output in clear text
any easy method to parse the data?

```
func iplocation() {
    var ip string
    fmt.Print("Enter IP Adress: ")
    fmt.Scan(&ip)
    lip, err := http.Get("http://ipinfo.io/" + ip + "/geo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    defer lip.Body.Close()
    loc, err := ioutil.ReadAll(lip.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    lstring := string(loc)
    fmt.Println(lstring)
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

**output**

```
{
  "ip": "216.58.208.78",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.4192,-122.0570",
  "postal": "94043"
}
```

***I want to get output just like this***

```
  ip: 216.58.208.78,
  city: Mountain View,
  region: California,
  country: US,
  loc: 37.4192,-122.0570,
  postal: 94043
```

*not in json format*

Comment: Whats 'plain text'?

Comment: ip  216.58.208.78
city  Mountain View
 region California
  country US
  loc 37.4192,-122.0570
  postal 9404

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Comment: JSON is plain text, can you detail what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: go doc is really hard to understand

Comment: i want to parse the output data properly.. without braces and symbols

Comment: "without braces and symbols" is not a suitable definition of "plain text".

Comment: `ip: 216.58.208.78
city: Mountain View
region: California
country: US
loc: 37.4192-122.0570
postal: 940431`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. You need to unmarshal the JSON you have received from the server. The [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will do this for you.
2. You need to output the data in a format you desire. You can just use `fmt.Printf` or similar for that.

Comment: *thanks, can you explain this with example? how to accomplish this in above code*

Comment: There are countless examples already on the internet, in the godoc for the json package, and even on SO.